# Is there a way to make my Firebase query more secure?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Basically, we want our app to sign in with a username/password instead of email/password. I had the idea to query the realtime database given the username and it would return the email associated with that username (each username is unique btw) and then continue to sign in with email/password. The sign in works, but I realize this could pose a security risk. The rules for our realtime database are as follows:

```
"rules": {
    "user":{
        ".read": true,
        ".indexOn": ["username"],
        "$uid": {
            ".write" :"$uid == auth.uid && auth != null",   
        }  
    }
}
```

Obviously, write would only by allowed by authenticated users, but would this be a problem having read be true for everyone? This is the only solution that I can think of.

Comment: What is the security risk you're trying to avoid?  The only way to effectively write security rules is to first understand exactly what you want to allow or deny, and code them to suit those requirements.  If you don't have clear requirements, then there's not much to do.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response! I think the main issue we have is having our data have read access by everyone when the website runs the query. It's not that it gets printed anywhere in the console, but if someone were to have someone's username and were to run the query in the console, then they would obtain their email, which we do not want.

Comment: Right, so, you'll have to isolate only the data you do want them to be able to read, and give appropriate access to it based on your requirements.